# Clojure defrecord - how to update multiple vectors within

Tags: clojure

I have a datatype defined with defrecord, which contains two vectors:

```
(defrecord MyType [a b])

(def mytype (->MyType [1 2 3] [4 5 6]))
```

I want to have a function update both vectors and return a new MyType. The only way I can think of to do that is via nested assoc calls:

```
(defn mutate-mytype [mytype x y]
  (assoc mytype :a (assoc (:a mytype) x y)
                :b (assoc (:b mytype) x y)))
```

Example output:

```
user=> (mutate-mytype mytype 1 7)
#user.MyType{:a [1 7 3], :b [4 7 6]}
```

Question: Is there a better way to write that mutate-mytype method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation is perfectly fine.

There are a few alternatives, e.g. you might consider using `assoc-in` and the `->` threading operator:

```
(defn mutate-mytype [mytype x y]
  (-> mytype 
      (assoc-in [:a x] y)
      (assoc-in [:b x] y)))
```

This doesn't really have any advantages over your approach in this case, but it might make the code more readable if you had more deep nesting going on.

Comment: I didn't know you could use -> like that. I'm a little confused how it knows what :a and :b are in the inner call, but that's neat that it works that way.

Comment: @WesFreeman "How it knows what :a and :b are"? I'm not clear about what you mean by the question. Keep in mind that all the threading macro does is expand this to `(assoc-in (assoc-in mytype [:a x] y) [:b x] y)`